# Speech Recognition in for virtual counter

Tags: machine-learning, speech

This may be a dumb question but is there a good way to separate the sound coming from the microphones which are kept close to each other. I have looked into blind audio source separation, etc. But I've not found something as effective yet. It's for my school project.

Comment: Since this is your first question, I will help you frame your question a little better. First of all you need to show some code/links of what you have done to solve your problem. Secondly, sounds come out from speakers and not microphones. You will need to clarify that part as well. Finally, assuming that you are capturing sounds from two microphones kept together, then you will need to specify the sound source as well.

Comment: And to those users who start down-voting, we need to be a little more tolerant and help new users frame their questions, rather than discouraging them by down vote.